# C# Login Form (passing username from 1 form to another accessing database)

Tags: c#

I got 2 forms (1)Login (2)User basically User types in username & password checks database if its found they are directed into (2)User I want to pass Username from form (1) to (2) so I can refer to that and display user account information in the (2) form. I've this this code but not sure if its right cause it wont display in textbox(Username) on form 2.

//Form(1)

```
   public FormLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        public string StrUsername{
        get { return txtboxUser.Text; }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main ss = new Main();
        ss.Show();
        txtboxUser.Text = String.Empty;
        txtboxPass.Text = String.Empty;
    }


    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Graded unit Dev\BlackMarch\BlackMarch\bin\Debug\DataBaseBM.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From UserData where Username= '" + txtboxUser.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtboxPass.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);




        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            User ss = new User();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username Password");

        }
    }
```

//Form User(2)

```
 private void btnHotelResort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelPicture.Visible = false;
        var formlogin1 = new FormLogin();
        txtUsernameUser.Text = formlogin1.StrUsername;

    }
```

Comment: You never show the form you create. Consequently, the text of the TextBox will stay empty by default and `StrUsername` just represents this value.

Answer (score 2):

Add property in `User` form and set it on successful login:

```
public string UserName {get; set;} // In User form
```

Upon logon:

```
this.Hide();
User ss = new User();
ss.UserName = txtboxUser.Text;
ss.Show();
```

Then, you can access `UserName` inside `User`

```
txtUsernameUser.Text = UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FormUser(2) must be  :

```
public FormLogin frm;
 public FormUser (FormLogin frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frm=frm
    }

 private void btnHotelResort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelPicture.Visible = false;
        txtUsernameUser.Text = frm.StrUsername;

    }
```

In your From1 :

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main ss = new Main(this);
        ss.Show();
        txtboxUser.Text = String.Empty;
        txtboxPass.Text = String.Empty;
    }
```